# Why does deleting an iCloud photo on my Mac not delete it from my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, mac, icloud, photos

I have turned on iCloud Photos sync. When I remove a photo on the Mac, I can see that it’s also deleted from iCloud on the web. I would like it to disappear on my iPhone as well, but it’s still there.

Although the confirmation dialog is appearing when I try to delete it, it says that the photo will be deleted from iCloud and all synced devices.

Comment: How long are you waiting for the delete to happen on the iPhone?  It's not instantaneous and could take 24-48 hours based on when it does the iCloud sync.  I'm assuming all these devices are signed-in with the same Apple ID.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @fsb. I've been waiting for about 6 hours. And yeah, both devices use the same Apple ID. I didn't know that it takes so much time to sync these changes. I thought that the Photos app makes a request to the server as soon as I open the app. But maybe it works differently under the hood. So should I just wait or is there any way how I can speed up this process?

Comment: One other thing that may be at play, it's my experience that Photos on iOS doesn't sync unless on a Wifi connection.  If your happen to be using a cellular connection, that might add to the delay.

Comment: @Charlie74 Most of the time the phone has been on the WiFi connection since I made the deletion.

Comment: If you take a photo on the device not syncing properly, does it appear on iCloud? Is it plugged in and connected to Wi-Fi?

Comment: @Ezekiel yes. As soon as I take a photo it appears in the Photo Library on my Mac

Answer (score 2):

I woke up this morning and noticed that photos were finally removed from my iPhone too.

I think the reason why it took so long is that yesterday I'd just turned on the sync with iCloud on my iPhone and immediately started deleting some of the unsuccessful or duplicated photos on the Mac. And these deletions were not immediately applied to the iPhone because (I suppose) they were added to the end of the sync queue. Thus the photos were deleted from the iPhone only after the whole library was uploaded to the iCloud.

So for future reference, if anybody ever faces this scenario, keep calm and just wait - eventually your changes will be applied.